# Not able to parse description from feature file when trying to import Cucumber tests into XRAY

Tags: cucumber, jira, cucumber-java, x-ray, jira-xray

I am trying to import this feature file into XRAY in order to create a new Cucumber test in XRAY.

As of now Description field is mandatory for creating any test in our Xray project.

How do we parse the description from the feature file? What id the format for me to enter the description in the feature file so that it is successfully parsed.

I have tried to enter a a comment(example- '# this is my description') but the API still complained that description is missing.

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Suchi

Answer (score 0):

The process of importing Cucumber Scenario(s)/Scenario Outline(s) and respective Background, if they exist, from .feature files is detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Importing+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST).

Currently, the "Description" field in the Test issues being created is not filled. So, you'll need to ask your Jira administrator to set Description as an optional field for Test issues; this is possible with Jira's "field configurations".

Another option is to configure the Jira workflow for Test issues, and set the Description field during the post-function associated to the create transition.

I would recommend you to [reach out to Xray support team](https://jira.xpand-it.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and ask for an improvement request, so the team can see if this can be implemented in some release in the future.